# ViewPager can replace ActivityGroup?

Tags: android, activitygroup, android-viewpager

I am doing an application similar to Viber or Linphone, a SIP application basically. I have a main tabhost at the bottom of the screen. And inside each tab I set different activities(for example the historic). I have done this using ActivityGroup. Is that the right approach? As I have seen that ActivityGroup is deprecated, but I dont want to use fragments(most of phones dont support API 11). I have seen the ViewPager component, could be also an alternative? I guess I can change the event onFlip with my finger for the onClick on a specific botton. Am I doing it right using Activitygroup, or should I change to another component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the kind of thing you are describing can be done using a simple TabActivity.

I'm not sure why you decided to use ActivityGroup, but regarding your hesitation related to fragments - you can use the [Compatibility library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html), which will give you fragment support for older platforms, albeit with some limitations.

Comment: I want to use ActivityGroup case the tabActivity is more difficult to customize in the graphical aspect.

Comment: Actually I have solved using TabActivity, setting to GONE visibility of the tabBar and using setCurrentTab in the onClick of my personal layout.

Comment: even the TabActivity is deprecated!